# How to nest multiple postgreSQL tables into one json?

Tags: json, postgresql

I just started with postgreSQL and right now I'm trying to get a tree structure of related table entries.

Let's say I have for example following tables:

streets, properties, buildings, floors, rooms

```
streets (columns: id, name)
properties (columns: id, name, street_id)
buildings (columns: id, name, property_id)
floors (columns: id, name, building_id)
rooms (columns: id, name, floor_id)
```

Now I try to get a output like:

```
[{
"id":1,
"name":"Main Street",
"properties": [{
     "id":"1",
     "name":"First Property",
     "buildings": [{
          "id":"1",
          "name":"Main Building",
          "floors": [{...},{...}]
        },{
          "id":"2",
          "name":"Shed",
          "floors": [{...},{...}]
        }]
   },{
     "id":"2",
     "name":"Another Property",
     "buildings": [{...},{...}]
   }]
}]
```

For now the query is like this:

```
SELECT s.*, json_agg(p.*) as properties
FROM streets AS s 
INNER JOIN properties AS p ON s.id = p.street_id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Which gives me the output as above for the two layers streets and the properties inside the streets result. But I can't get my head around how to nest the buildings into the properties and then the floors into buildings, ...

I could add another INNER JOIN and json_agg() for them, but then they would not be inside the properties.

Any suggestions how I should approach this?

EDIT:

Thanks Dmitry your answer works perfectly fine. But now lets say I want to store all the data in the same table called "locations" and link the entries by "parent_id"

So I have the columns:

id, name, type, parent_id

With the following code I get the wrong hierarchy.

```
WITH RECURSIVE locationtree AS (
   SELECT
      e.*,
      null::json as parent
   FROM location e
   WHERE parent_id IS NULL

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
      e.*,
      row_to_json(et.*) as parent
   FROM location e
   INNER JOIN locationtree et
      ON et.id = e.parent_id
)
SELECT *
FROM locationtree;
```

This results in
     Room
        Floor
           Building
              Property
                 Street

But I want as in the initial question and in Dmitry's answer following structure
     Streets
        Properties
           Buildings
              Floors
                 Rooms

Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **[CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html)** expressions query may be the following:

```
WITH floors_agg AS (
    -- get floors with nested rooms
    SELECT 
      f.*,
      json_agg(r.*) nested_rooms 
    FROM floors f
      LEFT JOIN rooms r ON r.floor_id = f.id
    GROUP BY 1
), buildings_agg AS (
    -- get buildings with nested floors
    SELECT 
      b.*,
      json_agg(fa.*) nested_floors 
    FROM buildings b
      LEFT JOIN floors_agg fa ON fa.building_id = b.id
    GROUP BY 1
), properties_agg AS (
    -- get properties with nested buildings
    SELECT
      p.*,
      json_agg(ba.*)
    FROM properties p
      LEFT JOIN buildings_agg ba ON ba.property_id = p.id
    GROUP BY 1
), streets_agg AS (
  -- get streets with nested properties
    SELECT
      s.*,
      json_agg(pa.*) nested_properties
    FROM streets s
      LEFT JOIN properties_agg pa ON pa.street_id = s.id
    ORDER BY 1
)
SELECT json_agg(sa.*)
FROM streets_agg sa;
```

Comment: wow, thats what I wanted. Now it looks quite easy.. :)

But let's say now I store all the data in the same table with parent_id
So streets,properties,buildings,floors,rooms i would all store in one table called location with the columns "id", "name", "type", "parent_id"

How would I get the tree for that?

Comment: @sking what is relation between `streets_agg` (or just tables defined initially) and `location` table ?  `location.id = streets.location_id` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My second question is how would I get the same output as from your result when I would store all information in one table. So I would drop the tables streets,properties,buildings,floors,rooms and instead create a new one with location. This would contain then all street, building, property, floor and room names.. So entries would be { ID: 1, name: Main Street, type: street, parent_id: null} { ID: 2 name: school ground, type: property, parent_id: 1} ....